# Route matching in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to make a page with url `users/:userId` where userId will be (java, cpp, c).So in home page if click on java button it will open a page wit url `users/java`, similarly for c and cpp.All these pages will have same layout with different data.For this I made a simple component as `Lang.jsx`

```
export class Lang extends Component{
  render() {
  const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
       <h1>{data.lang}</h1>
      </div>);
  }
}
```

In Router class we have to write something as

```
<Route path="users/:userId" component={Lang} />
```

But it is not clear how to pass `userId` in router and 
load `Lang` for each url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Link for these java, cpp, c, like this:

```
<Link to='users/java'>Java</Link>
<Link to='users/cpp'>Cpp</Link>
<Link to='users/c'>C</Link>
```

If you are using `history.push()` then write it like this:

```
hashHistory.push('users/java');
```

Note: You can make that userid optional because if you don't pass userid it will not match to any route, write it like this to make it optional:

```
<Route path="users/(:userId)" component={Lang} />
```

Now if you don't pass anything then also it will open the Lang page.

One more thing since you are passing the parameter by name userId, so it will available by `this.props.params.userId` not by `this.props.data.lang`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do here, but if you have a look at `this.props` inside of lang, there will be a `params` key (`this.props.params`), which will be an object containing the `userId`.

eg:

```
this.props = {
  params: {
    userId: '1234',
  },
}
```

This means that when you go to `/user/1234`, the `userId` key will have the value of `1234`.

I'm not really sure what you're expecting the value of `data.lang` to be.  Are you wrapping the routes in another route that provides that prop?  What library are you using for lang?